# Editing row labels in {gt} in R

Tags: r, gt

I have created a gt table using the following code:

```
bovids.summary.carb <- 
  bovids %>% 
  mutate(across(Member, factor, levels = c("UpperBurgi", "KBS", "Okote"))) %>% 
  group_by(Dep_context, Member, Tribe) %>% 
  summarize( 
    mean_d13C = mean(d.13.C, na.rm = TRUE), 
    median_d13C = median(d.13.C, na.rm = TRUE), 
    range_d13C = max(d.13.C, na.rm = TRUE) - min(d.13.C, na.rm = TRUE)) 
#table
gt(bovids.summary.carb) %>% 
  tab_header(title = "Mean, median, and ranges of d.13.C values by Tribe across Depositional Environemnt and Member")%>%  
  fmt_number(columns = vars(mean_d13C, median_d13C, range_d13C), decimals = 2)%>% 
  sub_missing(missing_text = "--")%>% 
  cols_label(mean_d13C = "Mean", median_d13C = "Median", range_d13C = "Range") %>% 
  tab_style(style = cell_text(weight = "bold"), 
            locations = cells_body(columns = "Tribe"))
```

And I get an output like this: [image]

I've played around with some other tab_style calls trying to get the Deltaic - Upper Burgi (and equivalents) are bold instead of the Tribe names. Any suggestions?

Here is a subset of the data:

```
> dput(bovids)
structure(list(CA = c("41", "131", "131", "131", "131", "131", 
"131", "131", "131", "131", "131", "131", "131", "1A", "1A", 
"1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "6", "6", 
"6", "6", "8", "8", "11", "1A", "1A", "1A", "6/6A", "6/6A", "6/6A", 
"6A", "8A", "8A", "8A", "8A", "8A", "8A", "8A", "8A", "8A", "8A", 
"8A", "41", "41", "41", "41", "41", "41", "41", "41", "41", "41", 
"41", "41", "41", "41", "41", "41", "41", "41", "41", "41", "41", 
"41", "105", "105", "41", "105", "105", "105", "105", "105", 
"105", "105", "105", "105", "8", "103", "131", "131", "100", 
"123", "6"), Member = c("Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", 
"Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", 
"Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", 
"Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", 
"Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", 
"Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", 
"Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", 
"Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", 
"Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", "Okote", 
"Okote", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", 
"UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", 
"UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", 
"UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", 
"UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "KBS", "KBS", "UpperBurgi", 
"KBS", "KBS", "KBS", "KBS", "KBS", "KBS", "KBS", "KBS", "KBS", 
"KBS", "KBS", "KBS", "UpperBurgi", "UpperBurgi", "KBS", "KBS"
), Dep_context = c("Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", 
"Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", 
"Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", 
"Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", 
"Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", 
"Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", 
"Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", 
"Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", 
"Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", 
"Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", 
"Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", 
"Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", 
"Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", 
"Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", 
"Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", 
"Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", 
"Deltaic", "Deltaic", "Fluvial ", "Fluvial ", "Deltaic", "Deltaic", 
"Deltaic", "Lacustrine", "Fluvial "), Family = c("Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", 
"Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae", "Bovidae"), Tribe = c("Alcelaphini", 
"Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Bovini", "Tragelaphini", 
"Tragelaphini", "Tragelaphini", "Tragelaphini", "Tragelaphini", 
"Tragelaphini", "Tragelaphini", "Tragelaphini", "Reduncini", 
"Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", 
"Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", 
"Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", 
"Tragelaphini", "Tragelaphini", "Tragelaphini", "Tragelaphini", 
"Alcelaphini", "Bovini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Alcelaphini", 
"Alcelaphini", "Reduncini", "Tragelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", 
"Reduncini", "Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Antilopini", "Alcelaphini", 
"Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Reduncini", "Aepycerotini", "Aepycerotini", 
"Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", 
"Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Tragelaphini", "Aepycerotini", 
"Aepycerotini", "Aepycerotini", "Aepycerotini", "Alcelaphini", 
"Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", 
"Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", 
"Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", 
"Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Alcelaphini", "Antilopini", "Reduncini", 
"Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", 
"Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Reduncini", "Tragelaphini", 
"Tragelaphini", "Tragelaphini", "Tragelaphini", "Tragelaphini", 
"Tragelaphini", "Tragelaphini"), Genus = c("", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", ""), d.13.C = c(0.4, 0.7, 0.6, -1.2, -1.2, -6.4, -5, -3, 
-2.7, -6.5, -6.2, -2.7, -5.7, -1.2, -0.4, -0.7, 0.8, 0.8, -2, 
0.6, 0.4, -1.2, 0.6, 2.8, -0.3, -1, -0.8, 1, -1, -4.8, -5.9, 
-3.9, -8.7, -1, 0.8, 1.7, 0, -1.1, 0.3, -2.3, -11.5, -0.3, -1.1, 
-1.9, -0.1, 2.2, 1.5, -0.3, 0.2, -1.2, 0.8, 0.9, -2.4, 1.2, 2.4, 
0.1, -0.7, -1.7, 0.6, 0.1, -2.4, -1.7, -0.9, 0.3, -3.3, 1.5, 
1.7, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.8, 1.2, 1, 1.5, 1.3, 1, 0.5, 0.7, 1.3, 
1.5, 2.7, -0.2, 2.1, 2, 0.6, -3.3, 1.3, 0.8, -3.2, 0.1, -1.2, 
0.2, -1.6, -0.4, 0.3, 0.3, -4.2, -2.6, -4.5, -5.3, -8.1, -8.7, 
-8.1), d.18.O = c(0.9, 0.8, 3.1, 1, 2.3, 1.5, 1.6, 2.5, 4.3, 
1, -2.1, 2.7, 2.5, -0.1, -0.3, -0.6, 1.1, 0.5, -1, 1.3, 0.3, 
0, 0.9, -0.6, 1.7, 0.5, 0, 3.9, -3.4, 0.1, -1.1, 0.2, -0.2, 1.6, 
4.1, 4.2, 0, 2, 2.9, -0.4, 2.1, 2.5, 0.1, -0.8, 0.7, 1, 3.2, 
-1.4, 5.3, 4.1, 2.5, 3.2, 0.4, 1.9, 1.2, 1.7, -0.1, -2.1, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.2, 1.8, -2.3, -3.6, -1.8, -0.4, -1.6, -0.7, 0.1, -1.1, 
-1, -0.3, 0.1, -0.7, -1.1, -2.3, -0.8, -3.7, -2.2, 2.6, 1.3, 
1.1, 1.7, 1.5, 2.2, 1.2, -1.4, 0.3, -0.6, -0.4, 1.5, 0.3, -0.6, 
-1.6, 0.6, -4.3, 3.3, 2.4, -1.3, 0.4, 1.4, 3.7, 0), Age.range = c("1.55-1.4", 
"1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", 
"1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", 
"1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", 
"1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", 
"1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", 
"1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", 
"1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", 
"1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", 
"1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", 
"1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", "1.55-1.4", 
"1.55-1.4", "2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", 
"2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", 
"2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", "2.1-1.9", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -103L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've tried to use cell_row_groups() but got a warning message " "Since gt v0.3.0, 'columns = vars(...) has been deprecated. Please use 'columns = c(...)' instead and the same bolded table appears. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the order I did group_by().

Comment: I think you need gt_summary, Could you provide the bovids data?

Comment: @TarJae Data is in the edit!

Answer (score 0):

To style the row group headers use `cells_row_groups()` instead of `cells_body` in `tab_style`

Using some fake example data based on the `gtcars` dataset:

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

bovids.summary.carb <- gtcars |>
  group_by(ctry_origin, bdy_style) %>%
  summarize(
    mean_d13C = mean(hp, na.rm = TRUE),
    median_d13C = median(hp, na.rm = TRUE),
    range_d13C = diff(range(max(hp, na.rm = TRUE)))
  )

gt(bovids.summary.carb) %>%
  tab_header(title = "Mean, median, and ranges of d.13.C values by Tribe across Depositional Environemnt and Member") %>%
  fmt_number(columns = c(mean_d13C, median_d13C, range_d13C), decimals = 2) %>%
  sub_missing(missing_text = "--") %>%
  cols_label(mean_d13C = "Mean", median_d13C = "Median", range_d13C = "Range") %>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_text(weight = "bold"),
    locations = cells_row_groups()
  )
```

[image]